# boost::optional<std::string> and implicit constructor from char[]

Tags: c++, string, boost, char, option-type

I have got used to initializing std::strings in the following way by letting the compiler figure out the magic involved

```
std::string my_string = "hello";
```

The following will not work as there is no explicit conversion between the two types:

```
boost::optional<std::string> my_optional_string = "hello";
```

This however does work:

```
boost::optional<std::string> my_optional_string = std::string("hello");
```

Now, would there be no way to daisychain the implicitly called single-arg constructors to allow the second form? The reason I ask (I don't want to bother you with details though) is that there are a whole bunch of classes with optional members to be populated. Having to explicitly type everything seems a burden (I do not so much worry about myself, but I am working on an open source API and would like to provide as much comfort to my users as possible). Any suggestions are appreciated.

---

**Edit**: Sorry guys I am new to this, should have provided more clarifying code examples. I have some classes (not modelled myself, just implemented them in C++) with optional members to be populated, like this:

```
Class Class1 {
public:
    Class1(const boost::optional<std::string>& arg_1, /*... ,*/ const boost::optional<std::string>& arg_n );
};
```

What I'd like my API users to be able to specify is:

```
Class1 my_class("hello","there",NULL,"stackoverflow");
/* ( Note: NULL is actually risky here, as some classes might also have members of type boost::optional<int> ) */
```

And not:

```
Class1 my_class(std::string("hello"),/*or*/boost::optional<std::string>("there"),boost::optional<std::string>(),std::string("stackoverflow"));
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

Since the constructor is marked `explicit`, why don't you call the constructor explicitly? `boost::optional<std::string> my_optional_string("hello");`

**After Edit**

Xeo already provides the solution, perhaps you could also use default arguments for your constructors:

```
Class1(boost::optional<std::string> = boost::optional<std::string>(), /*...*/)
Class1(std::string arg1, /*...*/) : 
member1(arg1), /*member2(arg2), etc.*/
```

Then you can all `Class1` like this:

```
Class1 my_class;
Class1 my_class("hello", "there"); // Rest of arguments use boost::optional
```

But, if you have to provide many constructors and possibilities, perhaps the above might not be a good solution, you could look into templating it to cut down on how much code you have to write.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks so much for answering. But sorry, I should have stated in my examples that I need to pass these in the constructors of my classes, please see the updated question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, the arguments are in a fixed order and the optional ones need not be the last.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution: Provide multiple constructors, one taking `char const*` or better `std::string`, and one taking `boost::optional`.

If you want this possibility for every argument by itself, it's way better to just template the ctor, though.

```
template<class A1, class A2, class A3 /*, ..., class AN*/>
Class1(A1 const& a1, A2 const& a2, A3 const& a3 /*, ... , AN const& aN*/)
  : _member1(a1)
  , _member2(a2)
  , _member3(a3)
/*, ...
  , _memberN(aN)*/
{ /* ... */ }
```

Btw, you shouldn't pass `NULL` for a non-used  `optional`, but `boost::none`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to boost::none, I knew there had to be a better way for that. I think I will look into a template specialization for optional<std::string> that has an additional constructor.